# Symfony add bundle and have my 'CoreBundle' realise it

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I currently have `Test\CoreBundle` which is intend on containing basic functions to get my website online (e.g. a splash page and basic admin panel).

What I want to do is be able to drop in `Test\UserBundle` and have the `CoreBundle` realise that I've added a new bundle so it can include this in the administrator panel. I thought I might be able to do something like:

In my `Test\UserBundle` I add a config.yml file such as:

```
include_admin:
    directory: "users"
    name: "User Management"
```

(i'd then add the bundle it to the AppKernel.php)

In my admin panel index:

```
$bundles = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.bundles');
foreach($bundles as $bundle){
  if(strpos($bundle,'Test') !== false){
    // access the config.yml file somehow for this bundle?
  }
}
```

I'd then be able to do something like this in my view:

```
<a href="/admin/{{ directory }}">{{ name }}</a>
```

I don't know if I'm going about this completely cack-handedly due to not knowing anything about sf.

Comment: In short, yes you can do this. To actually implement it is not so difficult, as long as your `UserBundle` is configured so that it can be used by other bundles. I suggest learning more about the way symfony handles vendors and Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a listener in CoreBundle that would listen for other Bundle's "participation".  I've done something similar below to build a navigation based on menu items for any bundles I wish.  You can modify the events & event listeners below to pass whatever data you need.

Basically, you create an Event & Event Listener in CoreBundle, and have each other independent bundle register the EventListener whenever the CoreBundle dispatches an event.

For example, in your CoreBundle, create an event:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class BundleEvent extends Event
{
    const EVENT = "core.bundle.find_bundles";

    private $bundles;

    public function addBundle($bundle)
    { 
         $this->bundles[] = $bundle;
    }

    public function getBundles()
    {
         return $this->bundles;
    }
}
```

Then create an event listener in your CoreBundle:

```
use Acme\CoreBundle\BundleEvent;

class BundleListener
{ 
    private $bundle_path;

    public function __construct($bundle_path)
    { 
         $this->bundle_path= $bundle_path;
    }

    public function addBundle(BundleEvent $event)
    {
         $event->addBundle($this->bundle_path);
    }
}
```

Then, in each of your Bundle's services.xml that you want CoreBundle to be aware of, use this:

```
<service id="acme.user.bundle_listener" class="Acme\CoreBundle\BundleListener">
    <argument>Acme\UserBundle</argument>
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="core.bundle.find_bundles" method="addBundle" />
</service>
```

Finally, in your CoreBundle (or wherever else you need to get this list), when you want to get all of the bundles you are looking for, run the event through the event dispatcher:

```
$bundles = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(BundleEvent::EVENT, new BundleEvent())->getBundles();

foreach($bundles as $bundle_path) {
    // .. do something
}
```

If someone else has a simpler way of accomplishing this, I'd love to know an easier/cleaner way!

Comment: Ok. I took over what you wrote and I get what this does however the only way the service will be triggered is if I'm in some way using `UserBundle`. So for instance if I just go to the page without having touched the UserBundle, it doesn't show it in the array!

Comment: Is your UserBundle registered in AppKernal, and is your UserBundle services.xml(or whichever config contains the Listener) registered in your UserBundle DependencyInjection?  Whether you are accessing your UserBundle or not outside of the listener is irrelevant.  As long as the services & events are registered properly, this should work fine.

Comment: Yep the UserBundle is registered in AppKernal. I used the services.xml you used (I know this works as I moved the services.xml into the CoreBundle and reloaded my test page under that bundle and it populated the array). However, if I load my AdminController where I have the list of `$bundles` the array isn't populated when the services.xml is within the UserBundle.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it's hard for me to figure out what's going on.  Are you using unique service IDs for each bundle that registers this listener? (acme.user.bundle_listener, acme.products.bundle_listener)

Comment: Not sure what the issue was but I created a new bundle and added a new service.xml file and it worked perfectly. Cheers for the help!

Comment: Haha .. glad to hear it!  I just created a blank symfony project with an empty bundle to test, and was going to report back that it worked fine for me.  Happy to hear that it worked.  Good luck!